# How to trigger on click event when user clicks on pagination page numbers in datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables

I am using datatables in which I want to trigger an on click event with alert box when user clicks on the datatable pagination numbers.

Below is the code I tried, but it works for next button.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    drawCallback: function(){
      $('.paginate_button.next', this.api().table().container())          
         .on('click', function(){
            alert('next') ;
         });       
    }
  });   
});
```

[Live Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ajbghfhh/)

Comment: Do you mean you want to show an alert when user clicks on a pagination button?  "trigger" is the opposite of handling an event.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, you're getting the next button by using this selector `$('.paginate_button.next')`, to get the page buttons, don't limit to .next, use `$('.paginate_button')` or, if you don't want next: `$('.paginate_button:not(.next)')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues that must be taken into consideration :

- The pagination buttons is generated over and over, so a delegated event handler is needed
- dataTables suppress or cancels the click event (I dont know why, it has been issued several times here on SO)
- You will need a selector to exclude next and previous buttons

I would do this :

```js
$('.dataTables_wrapper').on('mousedown touchstart', '.paginate_button:not(.previous):not(.next)', function() {
  alert('something')
})
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/943/**

---

**Update**. Disable previous / next buttons after each draw, including disable functionality :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   ...
   drawCallback: function() {
     $('.paginate_button.next').addClass('disabled').unbind();
     $('.paginate_button.previous').addClass('disabled').unbind();
   }
})
```

Comment: can i set previous and next buttons in disable state?

Comment: @SamaraSsr, see update, you can skip the last `unbind()` if the buttons still needs to be reactable...Wonder why you wish to do this ...?

Comment: we are providing blood donors list of 8 types in our site. we don't wanted to give the user full access to view all the donors list for the sake of getting in touch with them and collect their details too via a from. I replaced the alert with bootstrap modal. They would have to contact us for getting further donors list provided in our site. Thanks for your help in this :)

Comment: why this isn't working on mobile devices? In small screens, when I click on pagination numbers it is showing alert window fine but, after closing the alert it is shifting to the next page!

Comment: @SamaraSsr, I dont know, have not seen this. Try prevent the event from bubbling up: Add `e` to the `mousedown` handler and execute `e.stopPropagation()` before `alert()`

Comment: $('.dataTables_wrapper').on('mousedown', '.paginate_button:not(.previous):not(.next)', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation()
   alert('something')
})

tried this, still the same

Comment: @SamaraSsr, on mobile devices (at least some) touchstart is triggered along with mousedown, perhaps that is why is still fires, try `on('mousedown touchstart', ...` is not able to test this right now. If it works I'll update the answer.

Comment: @SamaraSsr, so the assumption with `touchstart` was right?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
       drawCallback: function(){
          $('.paginate_button', this.api().table().container())          
             .on('click', function(){
                alert('next') ;
             });       
       }
    });   
}
```

just remove .next

Comment: i want to prevent the default action of the pagination numbers. when user clicks on the 2 or 3 and so on button, only alert has to appear with out navigating to the next data page. ?